# Refactor and code placement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My edit action has a series of radio buttons in the view.  I want to fill in the value of the currently selected field. I managed to get this to work, though I feel the code could be better and also perhaps should be in the model.

controller:

```
      def edit
           @rating = Rating.find(params[:id])

       @a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g,@h,@i,@j = false
          if @rating.environ == 1
         @a = true
          elsif @rating.environ == 2
         @b = true
          elsif @rating.environ == 3
         @c = true
           elsif @rating.environ == 4
         @d = true
        .
        .
        .
        etc.
```

view:

```
         1<%= f.radio_button :environ, 1, :checked => @a %>
         2<%= f.radio_button :environ, 2, :checked => @b %>
         3<%= f.radio_button :environ, 3, :checked => @c %>
         .
         .
        etc..
```

Comment: This should probably be on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your model code? I am guessing a rating has many environs?

In any case, you can just loop through all of them in the view and make your :checked argument a boolean.

something like

```
 <% @environs.each do |env| -%>
   <%= f.radio_button :environ, env.id, :checked => (@rating.environ == env) %>
 <% end -%>
```

Comment: Environ is an attribute of rating.

Comment: Well my main concern is, I plan to have 10 attributes like this for @rating each with 10 instance variables and 10 elsif statements.  All this will mean 100 instance variables and 100 elsif statements in the edit method of the controller!

Comment: what do you need the instance variables and elsif statements for? i mean if they're all predicatble you can do a loop for that